# What to do with a modal on mobile using angular/pwa

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material2, progressive-web-apps

I am working on my first PWA using Angular Material 2. Now, I'm wondering how to handle modals on a mobile device, as I would rather show modals as a full page on mobile devices. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries, but you might also like to take a look at:

- [The layout package](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview)
- [Angular Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)